# Why does this code throw an exception? I thought RunWorkerCompleted could access UI elements

Tags: c#, wpf, timer, datagrid, backgroundworker

I have a datagrid in my WPF app, and when the app launches, I get deployment records from the database and load them into an ObservableCollection, which is bound to the datagrid.

Via a timer, I use a BackgroundWorker to go out and get any new records from the database and put them into a new ObservableCollection.

The, via RunWorkerCompleted I try to update the datagrid with the items in the new ObservableCollection.

However, I am getting a 'System.NotSupportedException'.

> Additional information: This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread.

I thought that I could access the UI controls from the RunWorkerCompleted method, but appearently there is something going on I don't understand.

> My code is below:

```
private void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Init the deployment collection
        deployments = DataAccess.GetDeployments();
        dgDeployments.ItemsSource = deployments;

        //Setup the background worker
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        bw.RunWorkerCompleted += bw_RunWorkerCompleted;
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;

        //Setup timer
        System.Threading.Timer t = new System.Threading.Timer(new System.Threading.TimerCallback(TimerProc));
        t.Change(10000, 0);           
    }

    private void TimerProc(object state)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show("Timer fired!");
        //Get the latest currentTime from the items in the grid
        DateTime? latestTime = DataAccess.GetDeployments().ToList()[0].CurrentTime;
        bw.RunWorkerAsync(latestTime);
    }

    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {         
        //Get new records that have changed since that time
        e.Result = (ObservableCollection<Deployment>)DataAccess.GetDeployments((DateTime)e.Argument);
    }

    void bw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Error.Message);
        }
        else if (e.Cancelled)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The operation was cancelled");
        }
        else
        {
            ObservableCollection<Deployment> newDeployments = (ObservableCollection<Deployment>)e.Result;

            foreach (Deployment d in newDeployments)
            {
                //Remove this new/changed deployment from the collection bound to the datagrid
                int index = deployments.IndexOf(deployments.Where(x => x.UniqueID == d.UniqueID).FirstOrDefault());
                if (index > -1)
                {
                    deployments.RemoveAt(index);
                }

                //Now add the new deployments
                deployments.Add(d);
                deployments.Move(deployments.IndexOf(d), 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e61819bd-dcb6-4d68-a490-1b3ad70147af/backgroundworker-calls-runworkercompleted-event-on-worker-thread?forum=wpf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The timer process `starts` the background worker in a different thread. Try starting the background worker in the GUI thread so the completed operation will run on the GUI thread and not the thread started from the timer.

Either `Invoke` the operation to the GUI thread or just make the timer a [`DispatchTimer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thank you! Putting it that way made the light bulb go off. Also, this verbage from MSDN on the DispatcherTimer clarified things a lot.

Comment: If a System.Timers.Timer is used in a WPF application, it is worth noting that the System.Timers.Timer runs on a different thread then the user interface (UI) thread. In order to access objects on the user interface (UI) thread, it is necessary to post the operation onto the Dispatcher of the user interface (UI) thread using Invoke or BeginInvoke. Reasons for using a DispatcherTimer opposed to a System.Timers.Timer are that the DispatcherTimer runs on the same thread as the Dispatcher and a DispatcherPriority can be set on the DispatcherTimer.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you everyone for the good information. It has helped me understand this issue better. Here is the code I used that ended up working for me.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate()
                    {
                        //Remove the old deployment
                        deployments.RemoveAt(index);

                        //Now add the new deployments
                        deployments.Add(d);
                        deployments.Move(deployments.IndexOf(d), 0);
                    });
```